# Python OpenCV VideoCapture read() cannot read a frame

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to capture image from usb camera, but cannot read a frame from an usb camera.

when I run this code in python 3.6.5

```
cv2.VideoCapture(1).read()
```

result

```
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:0] videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -2147024809
[ WARN:1] videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147024809
(False,None)
```

I've also tried with other usb camera (device 0). It can read a frame. But device 1 cannot read a frame.

Comment: Can you try the code from here: https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781785283932/3/ch03lvl1sec28/accessing-the-webcam

Answer (score 0):

You must define all parameter like:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)

video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, 0x32595559)

video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 25)
```

Comment: 0x32595559 -> YUY2 (fourCC)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer, instead of adding information as comments.